# Why the resolution of my custom softkeyboard does not increase on Android Tablets?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am customizing the softkeyboard sample of android SDK. The resolution of this keyboard is low and ugly when I install it on the 10in tablet. I mean it uses the resolution of PocketPc on the Tablet Pc. I get the width of softkeyboard using method getMaxWidth() and in both pocketpc (android 2.3) and tablet (android 3.2) it returns 545.

How can I increase the resolution of my keyboard depending on the resolution of my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

</manifest>
```

My reference is [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061623/how-can-i-fix-low-resolution-of-my-custom-soft-keyboard-view/8063115#8063115)