# How can I fix low resolution of my custom soft Keyboard View?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, ime

I am developing a custom softkeyboard using softkeyboard sample of android SDK for 10 inches tablet PCs.

**First question:** I noticed that the resolution of my keyboard is very low on tablet that is obvious in the following images. Actually in my keyboard area, the resolution is same as Pocket PCs resolution.

How can I change its resolution to normal resolution of tablet PCs (10in)?

In my softkeyboard `getMaxWidth();` returns 545 that is very low for tablet.

**Second question:** how can I change the font size of key labels?

Thanks a lot,

---

**My keyboard View:**
[image]

**My desired View:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer of my first question:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

</manifest>
```

My reference is [this link.](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/source/browse/branches/theme-support/project/?r=1142)

Comment: do you found the answer of second question?